# No provider for service at Injection Error and at No provider error

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcrtn.png) I am the new man to angular 2. I am getting No provider for service at injection error and no provider error even i specified the provider in the app module.
The code is 
                 **cribs.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CribsService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }


      getAllCribs()
        {
         return this.http.get('data/Cribs.json').map(res => res.json());
         }

   }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
enter code here
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CribsListingComponent } from './cribs-listing/cribs-
 listing.component';

 import { CribCardComponent } from './crib-card/crib-card.component';
 import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
 import {CribsService} from './service/cribs.service';

  @NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   CribsListingComponent,
   CribCardComponent,
    ],
   imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       HttpModule
        ],
   providers: [CribsService],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
```

My file heirarachy is : c:/User/Desktop/projectname/src/app/service/crib.service.ts
c:/User/Desktop/projectname/src/app/app.module.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

 })
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app works';  
 }
```

**cribs-listing.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {CribsService} from './../service/cribs.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-cribs-listing',
  templateUrl: './cribs-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cribs-listing.component.css']  
   })

export class CribsListingComponent implements OnInit {

Cribs: Array<any>;
error:String;

constructor(private http:Http,
private cribsservice: CribsService  
) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.cribsservice.getAllCribs()
.subscribe( 
  data => this.Cribs= data,
  error => this.error=error.statusText
);


 }

}
```

Comment: Please add the full and exact error message to your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, i added the screen shot of error message.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the import in the file that contains the provider or the file that injects the service.

Comment: i have added the file hierarchy, could you please review

Comment: I'm not using TS myself (only Dart) I can't help you with that except when I can try it myself in a Plunker. Perhaps someone else ...

Comment: Please add code of your `app.component.ts` file. How do you import it?

Comment: Where do you inject `CribsService` in constructor of `CribsListingComponent`?

Answer (score 2):

try giving the provider service name at the component level like belo

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-compoment',
    template: '<h1>{{ title }}</h1>',
    providers: [CribsService]
})
```

Comment: do i need to write this under app.component.ts?.

Comment: yes i write this under app.component.ts and it worked

Comment: may i ask the problem?. What exactly the problem was.

Comment: You should be aware that this changes the behavior. A service provided on a component can lead to as many service instances as there are component instances. If you provide the service **only** in the `AppModule` there will be a single shared instance (singleton). If it's the appcomponent, then there also can only be one instance, but other services provided at the `AppModule` can't inject this service, only services provided at components or other components.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Okay then what exactly the solution to get rid off the error

Comment: Fix the imports. I can't see a problem in the code you posted. If you can reproduce in a Plunker I can have a look.

Comment: The error you gave lead to this solution.  
The code which you gave actually defined the services well.
There is some problem with either the imports .Can you tell which component you have error? Also post exact error message